# SQL display MAX value not displaying correctly

Tags: sql, select, max

I need to display the highest height, first name,and last name of a patient from my table where gender is female. The issues is it is not displaying the highest height. It shows all Females. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT MAX(PatientHeight) as PatientHeight, FirstName, LastName
FROM Patients
WHERE Gender = 'F'
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

Edit:
I am adding the solution incase someone find this and wants to know more. This was back when I was just learning SQL and had no one I could ask so I posted it here. I want to thank User Jon Ekiz For briefly explaining and better way of approaching the problem. His solution below was exactly was I need to better understand SQL

Comment: So, you want the height of the tallest patient? i.e. you expect a single record to be returned?

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. Am I right that you want to find the tallest female patient and print her height, first name and last name?

Comment: Mike Parkhill, you are correct. Sorry for not being precise

Comment: Hi. Please edit your question in response to comments, rather than clariifying in comments. A question/answer should be self-contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't group by first name and last name and expect just one result. Use this instead:

```
select firstname
    , lastname
    , patientheight
from patients
where patientheight = (
            select max(patientheight) max_height
            from patients
            where gender = 'F'
            )
and gender = 'F'
```

BEtter solution is to use row_number and get the first result but not sure which dbms you are using.

Comment: This would return multiple records if there are multiple females with tallest height.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't clear enough, but following query should return what you're looking for.  Question:  What if multiple females have same height and are the tallest?

```
SELECT top 1 PatientHeight, FirstName, LastName
FROM Patients
WHERE Gender = 'F'
Order by PatientHeight desc
```

Comment: Thank you and to be more clear, I need only records that are the tallest to show. If there are multiples, than they must show as well. I am sorry for not being clear in my question.

Comment: In that case, Jon Ekiz already got you covered on answer.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do it?

```
SELECT TOP 1 PatientHeight,FirstName,LastName
FROM Patients
WHERE Gender = 'F'
ORDER BY PatientHeight DESC
```